# JQuery hides all element besides current element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 blocks and whenever I press on one of them, a checkbox appears inside it. If I click on another block the current checkbox will disappear and the other checkbox will appear which is good. The problem is that if I click on one block and the checkbox appears, when I press on that checkbox the block will disappear and it shouldn't.

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="item">1 <input class="hidden" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="item">2 <input class="hidden" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="item">3 <input class="hidden" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="item">4 <input class="hidden" type="checkbox"></div>
```

the following css code:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

and the javascript code:

```
$(".item").click(function(){     
    $(".item").find('input').hide();                    
    $(this).find('input').show('fast');
});
```

What can I do in order to hide all the checkboxes that are visible besides the current one  (the block I clicked on)?

Comment: As i wrote, the problem is this: 1) i click on the block and a checkbox appeares 2) when i click on the checkbox all the other checkboxes should hide and just the current one should remain. 3) The problem is that all the other checkboxes hide, including the current one witch appeares again. So i got a cliping witch it shouldn't be. Anyways, i already got an usefull answere witch i tested and it works perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the `.not()` filter like so

```
$(".item").click(function(){     
    $(".item").not(this).find('input').hide();                    
});
```

Edit:

You may want to consider if a user wants to change their mind, and re-enable all options. You can do that like so:

```
$(".item").click(function(){     
    var items = $(".item").not(this).find('input');
    if($('input',this).is(':checked')) items.hide();
    else items.show();                
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r8yBd/

Comment: `$(this).siblings().find('input').hide();` as another alternative.

Comment: This works perfect, thanks, you were very fast. I already rated a question few seconds ago and i have to wait 7 minutes to do that again. By the way, do you think that this question will help others to ?

Comment: Yep, theres quite a few different selectors that would work. I tend to try and stick close to what the OP posted though, just because people tend to simplify there issues for the sake of not bloating questions

Comment: @CrisanRalucaTeodora : No problem. All Stack overflow questions help others. I have answers to questions i posted years ago, that i have always found to be "simple", that still get votes every once in a  while. Whether a question/answer is useful is simply down to whether you know the answer or not to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".item").click(function(){     
    $(".item").find('input').addClass('hidden');                    
    $(this).find('input').removeClass('hidden');
});
```